# This query is choking the server. How can I improve it?

Tags: mysql, query, optimization

Following query is hogging a lot of resources, as much as that the queries are getting locked down & CPU usage goes through the roof!

The MySQL Processes list shows that as the number of requests for the queries increases, the time to completion also increases... It reaches to a point where queries just lock down.

As per the web host, there is some problem in the query design, but I am unable to figure it out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pet.*,ownrs.id AS ownrunique, ownrs.super,
(SELECT count(*) from comments WHERE pet.id=comments.petid) 
    AS noOfCom,
(SELECT count(*) from petfb WHERE pet.id=petfb.petid AND (feedback=1 OR feedback=100)) 
    AS newLikes,
(SELECT count(*) from petfb WHERE pet.id=petfb.petid AND (feedback=5 OR feedback=6)) 
    AS newDisLikes,
ownrs.name 
FROM pet, ownrs 
WHERE 1=1 AND pet.ownerID=ownrs.uniqueID AND catid=21
ORDER BY  date   DESC  LIMIT 0,10
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type         table       type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref                 rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             pet         ref     catid           catid       4       const               4758    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY             ownrs       eq_ref  uniqueID        uniqueID    52      petdb.pet.ownerID   1   
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  petfb       ref     petid,feedback  petid       4       petdb.pet.id        11      Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  petfb       ref     petid,feedback  petid       4       petdb.pet.id        11      Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  comments    ref     petid           petid       4       petdb.pet.id        1       Using index
```

[DESCRIBES of the 4 tables](http://pastebin.com/wHtGJYPw) (linked to avoid lengthy post).

---

EDIT 1

Based on Bohemian & a1ex07 replies, I am now using the following query. Everything is working OK but the noOfCom is being calculated wrongly for the pets that have >0 comments - it just equals to the total number of feedbacks from the petfb table for that particular pet, not the actual no of comments. For the pets that have no comments, it shows correct as zero. What could be wrong here?

```
SELECT pet.*, ownrs.uniqueID AS ownrunique, ownrs.diamond, COUNT( comments.id ) AS noOfCom,
SUM( feedback =1 OR feedback =100 ) AS newLikes,
SUM( feedback =5 OR feedback =6 ) AS newDisLikes
FROM pet
JOIN ownrs ON pet.ownerID = ownrs.uniqueID
LEFT JOIN comments ON pet.id = comments.petid
LEFT JOIN petfb ON pet.id = petfb.petid
WHERE catid =13
GROUP BY pet.id
ORDER BY DATE DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

---

EDIT 2

pet indexes:

```
Keyname     Type        Unique  Packed  Column          Cardinality     Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY     BTREE       Yes     No      id              40499           A    
petindex    BTREE       Yes     No      detail (200)    40499           A    
catid       BTREE       No      No      catid           62              A    
date        BTREE       No      No      date            40499           A    
detail      FULLTEXT    No      No      detail          1
```

petfb indexes:

```
Keyname     Type    Unique  Packed  Column      Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY     BTREE   Yes     No      id          1222897     A       
petid       BTREE   No      No      petid       71935       A     
feedback    BTREE   No      No      feedback    18          A     
deviceid    BTREE   No      No      deviceid    55586       A   
ownrid      BTREE   No      No      ownrid      671         A
```

---

EDIT 3 - SHOW CREATE TABLE petfb

```
CREATE TABLE `petfb` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `petid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `feedback` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=Like 100 = Hidden Like  5=Inappropriate  6=Dislike  7=Duplicate  8=Wrong Type',
 `fbdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `ownrid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `deviceid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `sugcatid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `petid` (`petid`),
 KEY `feedback` (`feedback`),
 KEY `deviceid` (`deviceid`),
 KEY `ownrid` (`ownrid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1215274 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: I would add an index on `(catID, Date, id)`

Comment: And probably on `(petid, feedback)` on the `petfb` table.

Comment: @ypercube: all those are already indexed. Post has been edited to reflect the same.

Comment: @ΒufferStack: No, your linked code shows no compound index.

Comment: @ypercube: not in the linked code. I just made EDIT 2 in the question. Perhaps, a refresh is required at your end.

Comment: Can you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE petfb` output? (just this one, so not much clutter) You don't seem to have any **compound** index at all. All you indexes are related to one column.

Comment: @ypercube: `SHOW CREATE TABLE petfb` now added. I have no idea about compound index, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to do `COUNT( DISTINCT comments.id )`, not `COUNT( comments.id )` in your last query .

Update. Assuming petfb.id is a primary key in petfb,

```
select pet.*, ownrs.id AS ownrunique, ownrs.super, 
count(distinct comments.id) AS noOfCom, 
count(distinct case when feedback=1 OR feedback=100 then petfb.id end ) AS newLikes, 
count(distinct case when feedback=5 OR feedback=6 then petfb.id end) AS newDisLikes 
from pet 
join ownrs on pet.ownerID=ownrs.uniqueID
Left join comments on pet.id=comments.petid 
Left join petfb on pet.id=petfb.petid and petfb.feedback in (1,5,6,100)
 group by pet.id
 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Yes.. that indeed solved the issue! Thanks! BTW, do you think the new designed query will significantly improve the performance? (PS: Can't vote up, repo<15!)

Comment: I think it should. At least you eliminated 1 subquery . I'd also change join condition a bit : `LEFT JOIN petfb ON pet.id = petfb.petid AND petfb.feedback in (1,5,6,100)`. It won't hurt in any case, but may improve performance. You can always check performance with `explain`: `Explain [your query]` and see the difference

Comment: I applied the new query.. but there seems not much improvement. The queries are getting in state 'Writing to net' as shown in WHM with >25 secs time. What would that mean?

Comment: Also, I would like to add that the `newLikes` & `newDisLikes` are also being shown wrong by some weird margins. For ex, for an actual likes of 5, it is showing 10 & in for some other pet actual likes of 20 are being shown as must as 494! I believe something is being multiplied here. Please see.

Comment: If you see writing to net, it usually means that either query returns a huge amount of data(in your case you have limit, so I guess you may have blob column) or there is a network issue .

Comment: The database is being accessed remotely from some other server. Could this be the issue related to writing to net? There is no BLOB column, table is as is shown in describes. BTW, what would you suggest for `newLikes`?

Comment: Check my updated answer, I hope it's what you need. Sorry if it has misprints

Comment: Yes, now it works perfectly! And, there seems to be improvement in performance. But I do see a lot of queries with status 'Copying to temp table' & 'Sending Data'. Is the fact that a server is accessing database from another server remotely could play a significant role in performance, or there is still scope of improvement in query design? Also, cannot we just avoid creation of temp tables? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BufferStack: As far as I remember mysql, it will create temp tables if columns in `group by` are different from `order by`. Also, are you sure you have to select `pet.*`?. Usually, when I see `*`, I feel like it's debug code.

Comment: It is not necessary to select pet.*, but I would sell have to select 11 out of the 17 fields. Will that make some difference if I call each manually?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3802/discussion-between-a1ex07-and-bufferstack)

Answer (score 2):

First add the following indices:

```
ALTER TABLE pet
  ADD INDEX catid_date_index 
      (catid, date) ;

ALTER TABLE petfb
  ADD INDEX petid_feedback_index 
      (petid, feedback) ;
```

Then try this query:

```
SELECT pet.* 
     , ownrs.id AS ownrunique
     , ownrs.super

     , ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM comments 
         WHERE pet.id = comments.petid  
       ) AS noOfCom

     , ( SELECT MAX(comments.comDate)     --- Unfortunately, you need
         FROM comments                    --- 2 subqueries if you want
         WHERE pet.id = comments.petid    --- 2 results from a table
       ) AS lastCom                       --- (comments)

     , ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM petfb 
         WHERE pet.id = petfb.petid 
           AND feedback IN (1, 100) 
       ) AS newLikes

     , ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM petfb 
         WHERE pet.id = petfb.petid 
           AND feedback IN (5,10)  
       ) AS newDisLikes

     , ownrs.name 
FROM 
        ( SELECT pet.*
          FROM pet
          WHERE catid = 21
          ORDER BY `date` DESC 
          LIMIT 0, 10
        ) AS pet
    INNER JOIN 
        ownrs
            ON ownrs.uniqueID = pet.ownerID 
ORDER BY p.date ;
```

Comment: Getting this implemented into the script is turning out to be quite a complex task, as the query is made by joining multiple parts based on different conditions. It's late night here. I will try it with a fresh mind in morning (about 12 hours from now) & update you then. Thanks.

Comment: Hi... Yes it does work & I also see that it doesn't require temp tables! But I cannot test it on live server until query can also support sort my comments. And for that I tried some changes, but it gives an expected error - `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`. [The is the edit](http://pastebin.com/nMvArc14). Please guide how to add this most efficiently. Also please note that I have removed the last line - it seemed that was not required as results are already sorted.

Comment: See my edit. if you add too many subqueries for a table, and it becomes slow, you should start considering using @Erwin's solution. With the `LIMIT 10` you have, I'd use this one.

Comment: You'll probably want to add another index on `comments (petid, comDate)` if this addition slows the query.

Comment: And don't delete the final `ORDER BY p.date`. If you want an ordering specify it. You only have 10 rows so it's not going to be slow. Why base the correctness of the result on a assumption of how things will work?

Comment: We don't want more columns (subqueries) than this & this lastCom is only required when sorting by "Comments". Also, I noted that putting up lastCom subquery in SELECT 'section' does not give desired results, as 0-10 results still do not have comments in that (sorted by date). I have modified it a little which does produce the desired result. [Check here](http://pastebin.com/RZZHCpjc) & see if does it efficiently. The EXPLAIN shows an ALL Type DERIVED query though. And, I verified multiple times, omitting last line sort still produced desired result. But, I will add it in future if required.

Comment: If you want only pets that have comments, it's a (slightly) different query.

Comment: What would the be? The one I finalized or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite each of your 3 subqueries as a `SELECT COUNT/SUM FROM ... GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT comments.petid, count(*) AS noOfCom from comments GROUP BY comments.petid

SELECT petfb.petid, count(*) from 
  (SELECT petfb.petid FROM petfb WHERE (feedback=1 OR feedback=100)) AS petlikes
  GROUP BY petlikes.petid

SELECT petfb.petid, count(*) from
  (SELECT petfb.petid WHERE (feedback=5 OR feedback=6)) AS petdislikes
  GROUP BY petdislikes.petid
```

Then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` these to your basic pet table.

```
SELECT * FROM 
( (pet JOIN owner ON ...)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN commentsquery ON ...
  LEFT OUTER JOIN likesquery ON ...
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dislikesquery ON ... )
ORDER BY ... [LIMIT ...]
```

I don't know by heart whether MySQL supports this syntax, but I think it's your only chance of a better-performing evaluation strategy.

EDIT

Unless the performance problems derive from lack of indexes or some such, of course (thought of that while driving home and the foregoing was already posted).

Comment: Do you mean if MySQL supports subqueries (derived tables). Of course it does.

Comment: Not sure why you made the 2nd the 3rd as nested while you let the 1st without nesting.

Comment: No, I meant the JOIN ... ON ... and LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON ...    I don't particularly follow the level of conformance and/or the additional extensions that any given SQL engine has vis-a-vis the standard.    For one reason or other, I'd expect those constructs to be available mostly in the engines that also have NATURAL JOIN, EXCEPT, etc ... (and those may not exactly be the majority).

Comment: You're right about the query nesting in the FEEDBACK queries.  The nesting isn't needed.

Comment: OK then. That's how I'd written the query if there wasn't the `LIMIT` on the pet table. (and to be honest I'd try both your and my version, just to be safe). One never knows with MySQL and various optimizations were added in some versions so it's version specific as well.